# Mongoid save method does not have the correct var values

Tags: mongoid

I am new to mongodb I have a method that updates some fields after_create

```
class Calculator
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :a, type: String
  field :b, type: String
  field :operation, type: String
  field :result, type: Integer
  field :number_of_calls, type: Integer, default: 1
  field :operator, type: String

  validates :operator, inclusion: { in: [ 'sum', 'difference', 'multiplication', 'division' ] }

attr_accessor :id, :a, :b, :operator, :result, :number_of_calls, :operation

after_create :calculate_results!
```

In my calculate_results! method I am updating some fields and then I am try to save the object.

```
def calculate_results!
  operation = a.to_s + OPERATORS[operator] + b.to_s
  result = [a, b].reduce(&OPERATORS[operator].to_sym)
  save!
end
```

When I trace the fields in the save! method they seems to be there.
But when I save the object all fields are nil.

Answer (score 0):

There are some related outstanding issues in Mongoid like https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4476.

In general, you are trying to save the model twice by persisting in an after_create callback. I suggest moving that code to before_validation_on_create which would be more efficient and I believe would also work as far as getting the values persisted.